# Y a-t-il des situations où l’élision entre « que » et « il » n’est pas préférée ?

Tags: élision

La question est assez évidente, mais pour la rendre plus claire, je pense à un contexte où on met l’accent sur « que ».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On ne fait jamais d'élision entre *qui* et *il*.

> Il joue avec **qui il** veut.

En revanche, on doit élider le *e* entre *que* et *il* :

> C'est avec eux **qu'il** veut jouer.

L'élision peut être absente s'il y a rupture entre *que* et *il*, ex :

> Il faudrait **que** :
>
> – **il** rentre à cinq heures
>
> – nous soyons là pour l'accueillir

et ne se fait pas non plus quand *il* n'est pas utilisé en tant que pronom mais comme nom commun :

> Il se peut que **il** soit cité en tant que mot.

En revanche, l'élision doit continuer à être réalisée avant des guillemets :

> C'est avec eux qu'« il veut jouer ».

Comment: Ça a été dû a mon inadvertance ; j’ai bien sûr pensé de « que », et d’élicion, et non liason (pardon !). Donc est-il toujours obligatoire, cette élision ?

Comment: Il se peut que *il* soit cité en tant que mot. Il me semble que c'est le seul cas qui déroge à la règle.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, je l'ajoute. Merci !